# Get the id from one to many modal - Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I need to get the list of product categories from the table. 
2 tables in total. tblProduct & tblProductCatLink
1 product can have many product category link.

tblProductCatLink consists of product_id, category_id
Now from my controller & view, i want to **get the list of categories belong to one product**.

Product.php

```
public function productcategorylink(){
    return $this->HasMany('App\ProductCategoryLink', 'product_id', 'id');
}
```

ProductCategoryLink.php

```
public function projects(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Project',  'id', 'product_id');
}
```

Controller

```
foreach ($projects as $project) {
   foreach ($project->productcategorylink as $value) {
        echo $value->category_id;
   }
}
```

The above code is returning first row of category for the product only. I had 3 rows of records for product 297 in my DB.

Comment: @Maraboc yes, it's using project model. No wording error here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to access the product category link from the view while I looping the product data

In a controller:

```
$products = Product::with('productcategorylink')->get();
```

In view:

```
@foreach ($products as $product)
    @foreach ($product->productcategorylink as $link)
        {{ $link->category_id }}
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: No, i need to access the product category link from the view while i looping the product data

Comment: Thanks. It's only returning first row of the data. Did i do anything wrong in my model relationship declaration? I have many row of data for product in my productcategorylink

Comment: @1myb the relationship looks fine. Just change it to `->hasMany` instead of `->HasMany`

Comment: For the with in this case. May i know how can i put a where clause on it?

Comment: Use constraints if you want to filter the relationship. https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161796/discussion-between-1myb-and-alexey-mezenin).

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `productcategorylink` and `projects`. So it would be

```
$projects = projects();
foreach ($projects as $project) {
   $productCategoryLink = $project->productcategorylink();
   foreach ($productCategoryLink  as $value) {
        echo $value->category_id;
   }
}
```

Comment: It's completely blank.

Comment: Does 'projects()' return anything?

Comment: Yes, it does. All the other data

Comment: does `$productCategoryLink = $project->productcategorylink();` return data?

Comment: Yes, it's all SQL query

Comment: So is the problem with the echo then?